# How to access Class Object in Closure Object?

Tags: php

```
<?php

class TryClass
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function closure(Closure $callback)
    {
        return $callback(function () {});
    }
}

$try = new TryClass('polat');

$try->closure(function ($reference) {
    print_r($reference);

    // not work
    // $reference->this->data
    // $reference::this->data
    // $reference::$this->data
    // $reference->{'this'}->data
});
```

**print_r() response;**

```
Closure Object
(
    [this] => TryClass Object
        (
            [data:TryClass:private] => polats
        )

)
```

How to access TryClass Object in Closure Object or How to access Static in Closure Object? Please help thank you so much.

By sending a closure function inside a class, I also want to access $this of that class inside that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a function to your closure, is that what you really want? So that your closure invokes a function? Instead, I think you just want to pass `$this` back to your closure to get to it:

```php
class TryClass
{
    public function closure(Closure $callback)
    {
        return $callback($this);
    }
}

(new TryClass())
    ->closure(
        function ($reference) {
            print_r($reference);
        }
    );
```

Output is:

```
TryClass Object
(
)
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/7Efpr

What you **can't** do is get access to the private variables without going through reflection, that would break incapsulation.